# Managed bean and datasource connections in ejb3.1

Tags: jdbc, ejb-3.0, dao, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have a bean (dbbean) that has datasource which is injected at runtime. this managed bean is used by many dao beans. I use ejb3.1 in jboss environment. I get frequent error saying closing the connection for you, please close them yourself. this dbbean is not singleton. should i need to manage the bean with scope? I have finally block that will close all database resources.
Note: I have postconstruct annotated method that will create a connection and predestroy annotated method which will close the opened connection.
thanks

Comment: Can you update post with relevant code for `dbbean`. Also, you can verify whether interceptor methods are being called with appropriate logging.